# Applications of spin models, integrability, and RG flows to information theory

Tags: statistical-mechanics, soft-question, information, spin-chains

As elucidated by E.T. Jaynes in his [seminal papers](https://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/articles/theory.1.pdf), there is a deep connection between information theory and statistical mechanics.

The nature of my question is somewhat soft, so I apologise for that. Anyway, does anyone know of any applications of spin model theory, integrability, and/or phase transitions (or in general RG flows) to information theory? (For instance in problems related to signal reconstruction)

Comment: One application is to the "reconstruction problem"; see, for instance, [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2667156) or [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1312555801) and references therein.

Comment: More generally, look at [this book](https://web.stanford.edu/~montanar/RESEARCH/book.html) and [these lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.2857).

Comment: There is also a connection between variational approach in deep learning theory and RG flows. You may be interested in paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.3831v1

Comment: Perhaps a book on the same topic with a catchy title: ["A Farewell to Entropy: Statistical Thermodynamics Based on Information"](https://books.google.ru/books/about/A_Farewell_to_Entropy.html?id=gnRckGEB3uQC&redir_esc=y)